# Windows Form en Vertical

Tags: c#, formularios, windows

solo necesito saber si un formulario de Windows Form puede tener una resolucion vertical o portrait (1080x1920) ya que es la resolucion que necesito para que la aplicacion encaje completamente en la pantalla del equipo donde se va a implementar, he intentado poner esa resolucion en el size del formulario pero me corrigue el valor vertical a 1100 en lugar de 1920.

Usando: Visual Studio 2019, C#

Comment: De casualidad tendrás la propiedad MaximumSize puesta a 1100?

Comment: Como bien plantea @Mateo; si en tiempo de diseño, cuando intentas modificar la propuedad  size del formulario te corrigue el valor vertical a 1100, la unica causa probable es que tienes la propiedad MaximumSize establecida a 1100, tendras que cambiar tambien esta propiedad.

Comment: Y qué ocurre si la resolución del usuario es menor? Vas a obligar a todos los usuarios a necesitar esa resolución?

Comment: @Arriel Maximum = Máximo. También hay una propiedad MinimumSize. Entre las dos limitan el tamaño que puede tener. Por otro lado, el dijo que la va a implementar en un equipo particular. No parece planear tener muchos usuarios.

Comment: @Mateo, gracias por tu comentario. Tal vez sea que estoy pensando en términos de usabilidad. A mí me parece más un "problema X -> Y", donde OP no puede controlar los estilos de su formulario, y su solución es setear la app en una resolución específica. Anyway, Suerte

Comment: No tengo maximun size a nada, simplemente el propio visual studio no permite poner una resolución mayor a la del equipo con el que estas programando, podéis consultar esta info aquí [https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.size?view=windowsdesktop-6.0&viewFallbackFrom=windowsdesktop-6.0%5D] yo busco una solución que sobrepase esto, pero no va a ser posible me temo, en otro post en el foro en ingles hay muchas soluciones, entre las cuales esta conectar 2 monitores para aumentar la resolución total, y eso lo arreglaría, pero en mi caso es vertical, así que no puedo.

Answer (score 0):

Traducción de respuesta del sitio en [inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56725860/10053314)

Este es el evento Load del formulario (puedes generarlo haciendo doble clic en el formulario en el diseñador). En este evento comprobamos las dimensiones actuales de la pantalla que contiene el formulario. Luego ajustamos el tamaño del formulario para que coincida. También movemos la posición del formulario a 0, 0 para que no se salga de la pantalla.

```
//El nombre de esta función será diferente para ti.
//genera esta funcion con doble click en el designer.
//El codigo de esta funcion es el que te interesa.
private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle screenSize = Screen.GetBounds(this); //Encuentra el tamaño de tu pantalla
    this.Top = 0; //mueve el formulario arriba
    this.Left = 0; //mueve el formulario a la izquierda
    this.Width = screenSize.Width; //setea el form a tu alto
    this.Height = screenSize.Height; //setea el form a tu ancho
}
```

Tambien puedes simplemente maximizar el form

```
    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

Comment: Con esto no puedo editar el diseño del formulario, lo que busco es cambiar el tamaño del designer para poner elementos en toda la pantalla.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con diseño de formulario? si lo tienes maximizado ocupará toda tu pantalla, sea del tamaño y forma que sea, no comprendo que es exactamente lo que requieres

Comment: Quiere aumentar el tamaño en tiempo de diseño para poder acomodar todos los controles, en tiempo de diseño...

Comment: Un form tiene un designer donde añades controles texto y demas, dicho form tiene un tamaño, en mi caso de 1080x1100. El problema es que la resolucion que quiero que tenga es de 1080x1920, es decir, bastante mas alto. Por consiguiente hay una diferencia de 820 pixeles entre el diseñador y la resolución deseada, si yo no puedo colocar ningún control en esos 820 pixeles, aunque en la pantalla deseada este maximizada, quedara en blanco porque solo puedo poner elementos en los primeros 1100 pixeles. [https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.size?view=windowsdesktop-6.0]